# How can I reference Xcode version inside of Podfile script?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

After upgrading my ios to Sonoma 14.0 I had to use this statement inside of my Podfile

```
# thanks to Armanoide ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37748
  post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', '_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION']
        end
      end
  end
```

to my build done.

However, some of my teammates are still using Xcode 14.3. To accommodate different Xcode versions, I need to add a simple if statement to determine the current Xcode version within the Podfile script.

How can I reference current Xcode version inside of this Podfile script? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in podfile,

```rb
xcode_version = `xcodebuild -version`.split("\n")[0]
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver!